# How to find deprecated functions in xcode 3.2.5?

Tags: iphone, deprecated, 3g

I have developed a iPhone/iPad project in XCode 3.2.5 version. I is working fine in 3Gs and above version devices. But, a single screen is not working(App Crashes) in 3G mobile. How to find the problem? It means, i think i was used some deprecated functions in my code, it may not supported in 3G mobile? How to find the solution? Can any one please help me?
I was used below things in my code;
 NSString, NSDate, NSDateFormatter, UIScrollView, UILabel, NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary.
  These are the things i have used in that class. I can't find which one is not supporting? Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API changes:

1. [3.0 -> 3.1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iPhone31APIDiffs/)
2. [3.1 -> 3.2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iPhone32APIDiffs/index.html)
3. [3.2 -> 4.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iPhone40APIDiffs/)
4. [4.0 -> 4.1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS41APIDiffs/index.html)
5. [4.1 -> 4.2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS42APIDiffs/index.html)
6. [4.2 -> 4.3](http://iOS%204.3%20to%20iOS%205.0%20API%20Differences)

Comment: Ya.. It is very helpful to find the deprecation. I will start my work now... thank you very much...

Comment: Hello Nekto.. I have read above documents and removed some coding from my actual project that was not supported in ios 3.0-3.1. But, still it getting crash while the app running in 3G mobile, especially the screen i have mentioned earlier. Can you guide me to solve this problem? Thanks.